# Using AngularJS, is it possible to identify routes without having a single page application?

Tags: angularjs

My application is using .NET MVC and needs to stick with .NET's routing mechanisms so defining a `$routeProvider` and then letting Angular handle routing and retrieval of an html template is not an option for me.

Still, it would be very valuable for me to grab the routing parameters of the current url within the context of my Angular controller.  So for example, if my current url follows this pattern:

`/products/{id}`

Then--hypothetically--I need only this in my Angular controller to retrieve the id:

`$routeParams.id`

Unfortunately, it appears as if it is all-or-nothing with the `$routeProvider` mechanism and that I have to either let Angular convert my application to a single-page deployment, or else I don't have access to route parameters from the Angular controller.

Am I missing something simple here?  Can I simply define the routes somewhere just so Angular understands the patterns that the URLs in my app follow?

Comment: $window.location.href in a controller maybe.then parse the url yourself.

Comment: Thanks @mpm, I might have to do that, but then I have no standard method for identifying a route pattern which kind of sucks.  It seems like this would already be a feature available within Angular. . .

Comment: you are confusing client routing and server routing...angular doesn't pay any attention to anything in url before a hash. As @mpm suggests, whatever you need from url you will need to parse from location object